# Does teleportation through a stable traversable wormhole break any known laws of physics?

Tags: general-relativity, wormholes

Is it merely the lack of our knowledge why stable traversable wormholes have not yet been invented to allow for instant travel between remote locations? Are we just not that advanced *yet*? Or does such a thing break some *known* laws of physics and therefore cannot be built in principle?

Let me write a bit of sci-fi here just to clearly outline what thing this question is about. This wormhole, as a mass product taking any and all means of conventional transport out of business, is manufactured looking literally like a pair of window frames (or doors, gates etc.) tied to each other by their face sides. Upon unpacking this product, the two gates (Gate 1 and 2) can be just taken apart and placed at any distance from each other. Whatever enters Gate 1 through its side A will not emerge out of its side B. Instead, it will emerge out of side A of Gate 2, wherever that is now. Similarly, entering side B of Gate 1 will just let the object out of side B of Gate 2.

Gate 1 will be installed at say "London International Teleport", Gate 2 will be transported (initially by conventional transport)ⁱ to wherever it needs to be at, say "New York International Teleport". Wealthy individuals will be able to install such gates at their homes so that getting from a mansion in Miami to another one in New Zealand will be just a matter of opening a door and walking through it like it was in the same building.

For simplicity let's assume that both gates are installed at the same altitude so that stepping through them does not involve any work against the gravity of Earth.

Physically, such a gate could work by say keeping two points in our 3D space tied to each other in some other, 4th dimension (like as if we lived in 2D world, on a piece of paper, making such a wormwhole would be just a matter of bending the paper and affixing two points on it to each other). But this question does not limit the physical implementation to any particular solution.

ⁱ It is also interesting if transporting such a gate through another gate would not be outlawed by physics.

Closely related, but not the same:

- [Do traversable wormholes exist as solutions to string theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4672/do-traversable-wormholes-exist-as-solutions-to-string-theory)
- [Would it be possible for a human to simply "step" through a traversable wormhole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/389698/would-it-be-possible-for-a-human-to-simply-step-through-a-traversable-wormhole)

Comment: It sounds like your first link answers the question. Do traversable wormholes exist? Not likely, but some people are not convinced. They would have to be built with negative energy matter. There is reason to believe there is no such thing.

Comment: @mmesser314 The statement that traversable wormholes exist as solution to string theory does not inherently mean that they do not break other laws of physics, unless it is known that string theory supersedes everything. The latter I just don't know, so I am asking this question abstracted from any particular theory.

Comment: Do you understand that we need to engineer and manipulate star-sized quantities of matter/energy (possibly negative!) to make something like this?  That's how close we are to "inventing" one.

Comment: @m4r35n357 No I do not. Hence the question. I hoped someone would explain like "It is not theoretically impossible but at the moment impracticable because of this and that".

Comment: Wormholes are the product of sci-fi writers and unscrupulous pop-sci authors.  We don't know what their properties should be, how to construct one, or even what to make it out of.  It is just a fantasy.  Sorry.